# is not of the expected type `REAL' in Common LISP (CL)

Tags: list, lisp

I made this function and I want to make it print like this :

> (RANGE ‘(0 7 8 2 3 –1))
>
> (-1 8)

;; print 'The range between the smallest number and the second smallest number in the list' and 'The largest number'

So I made code like this :

```
(defun my-range (list-of-numbers)
 (let* ((largest (max list-of-numbers))
        (msmallest (min list-of-numbers))
        (ssmallest (min (remove (min list-of-numbers) list-of-numbers)))
        (range (- msmallest ssmallest)))
  (list range largest)))
```

and I input function and number like the example on debug window :

> (my-range '(0 7 8 2 3 -1))
>
> Error: `(0 7 8 2 3 -1)' is not of the expected type`REAL'
>
> [condition type: TYPE-ERROR]

The error message was printed in the window...
What is the meaning of 'is not of the expected type 'REAL'?
And how I can fix this problem? And, Could you let me know which problems my code has?

I need your help.

Comment: what arguments are MIN and MAX expecting?

Comment: Also consider whether there is a better way of doing this (how many times are you traversing the list?  How many times are you copying it?)

Comment: @Rainer Joswig The argument will be 'list-of-numbers". Luckily, I found why the problem happened.

Comment: @tfb Then maybe is it better to use 'DOLIST' to solve this problem?

Comment: No. it is not *list of numbers*. MAX and MIN expect numbers. Not a list. Numbers!

Comment: @Rainer Joswig 
I know that MAX and MIN are used like this way : 
(min 3 5 7) => 3
(max 3 4 6) => 6

Then how I can evaluate the numbers in the list(list-of-numbers) that I input? How I can use MAX or MIN function from the list that I input?

Comment: `(reduce #'max list-of-numbers)`